# How to abort request when using ClientHttpRequestInterceptor in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest

If you read the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html) on `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept` method, it says:

> execute the request using ClientHttpRequestExecution.execute(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest, byte[]), or do not execute the request to block the execution altogether.

The second part of this statement is what I'm trying to achieve (block the execution altogether based on certain criteria). However, I've not been successful in doing so. I've done my research for few hours and still could not find any examples on how that is done.

I tried returning null and I get NPE later on in the flow as Spring tries to get statusCode from the response (exception below).

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.getHttpStatusCode(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:536)
```

**Edit**: Here's a simple interceptor for reference on what I'm trying to achieve:

```
  public class FailSafeInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
      try{
        return execution.execute(request, body);
      }catch(Throwable e){
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
```

**Possible Solution**: after sleeping on the problem, I managed to make it work with the following code (using MockResponse). But I'm not sure if that's the way the doc meant the method to be used. If there's a better way to do this, I'd appreciate the help.

```
  public class FailSafeInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
      try{
        return execution.execute(request, body);
      }catch(Throwable e){
        return new MockClientHttpResponse(new byte[]{}, HttpStatus.OK);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you show the code ?

Answer (score 1):

`MockClientHttpResponse` is from `spring-test` , it is awkward to include a testing class in the production codes.

If you want to abort sending the whole request once you detect something , just throw `RuntimeException` (or using the built-in `RestClientException`):

```java
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

        if(checkNeedAbortSendingRequst()){
           throw new RestClientException("Bla blab bla");
        }
        return execution.execute(request, body);   
    }
```

---

Update :

If you want to fail safe , your current solution looks good expect that I would use a non-200 status code if exception is caught (may be 500?). Since I also cannot find a `ClientHttpResponse` implementation that can be created from scratch or without any external dependencies in `spring-mvc` , I would copy `MockClientHttpResponse` from `spring-test` to the project to use.

Comment: I agree with your point on having test classes on prod code is awkward. My intention is to have a failsafe interceptor which will just log the error and move on without affecting the rest of the application flow. Throwing runtimeException goes against that. I don't want to have a catch block on all client code either.

Comment: Also, if that's what the doc meant, that'd be kind of dumb IMHO. Because of course throwing an unchecked exception will stop the execution of the rest of the method. I don't think that's what the javadoc meant by "or do not execute the request to block the execution altogether" because that basically applies to any method in Java.

Comment: So your intention mentioned in the comment is totally different from what you mentioned in the question which states you want to abort the request. Also , you don't need to explicitly catch  `RuntimeException` in all your client codes. And yes , if you want to "failSafe" , your current solution looks good , but I would not use "200" as the status code if exception is caught (may be use 500?) and will manually create an `ClientHttpResponse` rather than using `MockClientHttpResponse`...

Comment: (all good points on the question not being clear on my intentions. I'll edit it later tonight) Good point on the status code. On creating `ClientHttpResponse`, I had no luck on doing that. All implementations of that interface that I found, either didn't have a public constructor, or if it did, didn't seem very straightforward except for the `MockClientHttpResponse`. If you have a solution for that, please edit your answer with that code and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: ah , I also cannot find the implementation that allow to create fake `ClientHttpResponse` easily , so my advice is to copy  `MockClientHttpResponse` from the spring-test to the project codebase and use it

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to accomplish the same and chose a different route.

In my case, I didn't want to send requests to an external service in our development environment. We are using `RestTemplate` to interact with the external service (actually, we are using a [Spring Integration HTTP Outbound Channel Adapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#outbound) with a configured `RestTemplate`). However, I wanted as little configuration to change between environments as possible.

So the solution I came up with was to use a profile-scoped bean so that when the `dev` profile is selected, it replaces the `RestTemplate` bean used for external communication with one that never actually executes requests.

Here is my configuration:

```
package com.example.myproject;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

@Configuration
public class InfrastructureConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);

    /**
     * This configuration is used whenever we are running in an environment that
     * does not have access to external endpoints.
     **/
    @Configuration
    @Profile("sit")
    public static class FakeExternalConfig {

        @Bean
        @Qualifier("externalRestTemplate")
        RestTemplate externalRestTemplate() {
            // Returns a Rest Template which will always return HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT without actually executing the request.
            return new RestTemplateBuilder()
                    .additionalInterceptors(((request, body, execution) -> {
                        LOGGER.info("Fake external request sent. Method: {} URI: {} Body: {} Headers: {}", request.getMethodValue(), request.getURI(), new String(body), request.getHeaders().toString());
                        return new AbstractClientHttpResponse() {

                            @Override
                            public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
                                return new HttpHeaders();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public InputStream getBody() {
                                return new ByteArrayInputStream("" .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                            }

                            @Override
                            public int getRawStatusCode() {
                                return HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public String getStatusText() {
                                return HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.getReasonPhrase();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void close() {

                            }
                        };
                    }))
                    .build();
        }

    }

    /**
     * This configuration is used whenever we are running in an environment that
     * does have access to external endpoints.
     **/
    @Configuration
    @Profile({"test", "prod"})
    public static class ExternalConfig {

        @Bean
        @Qualifier("externalRestTemplate")
        RestTemplate externalRestTemplate() {
            return new RestTemplateBuilder()
                    .build();
        }

    }

}
```

I chose to implement `org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse` as an in-line anonymous class because I wanted this to be the only instance where it could be used and there aren't that many methods that need to be overridden. I chose to always return HTTP status 204 No Content because that seemed to make the most sense to me but any other status code could be chosen. (I was very tempted to use `I_AM_A_TEAPOT` but it is a 4xx status which is considered an error :( )